# C# number different formats

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I am working on a project that requires to parse data from a file and store it to MySQL database
the file has the following string in multiple formats

```
Ava. bytes -> 147.258.369
Ava. bytes -> 147.258.369,5
Ava. bytes -> 147,258,369
Ava. bytes -> 147,258,369.5
```

what is the best way to convert any of these formats to

```
Ava. bytes -> 147.258.369 => 147258369.0
Ava. bytes -> 147.258.369,5 =>147258369.5
Ava. bytes -> 147,258,369 => 147258369.0
Ava. bytes -> 147,258,369.5 =>147258369.5
```

thank you!

Comment: Is the decimal always only to the tenth?  Because what if you had 147.258 and 147,258 ...  You wouldn't have enough information to know if you meant 147.258 or 147,258.000

Comment: What is `123,456` ?

Comment: Is this fixed-width data where you can depend on the decimal (if any) always being in the same location?

Comment: What is `147.258.369,5`?

Comment: I know that if there is a decimal digit, it will only be one

Comment: so some are I guess European numbers

Comment: and others are in the US formats

Comment: @AlexAwad is dot or comma always followed after 3 digits? do you ever have instances like 123456.5 or 123456,5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to remove any dot or comma that is followed by three digits, and a string replace to substitute the final decimal comma for a period if there is one:

```
string n = "147.258.369,5";
var r = new Regex(@"[.,](?=\d{3})");
string n2 = r.Replace(n, "").Replace(',', '.');
```

**Edit:**

The string is then in InvariantFormat if you want to parse it to a decimal (but presumably you want the string since the .0 is important.)

To include the final `.0`:

```
if (n2.Length < 2 || n2[n2.Length - 2] != '.')
{
    n2 = n2 + ".0";
}
```

Comment: I admit this 3-liner is more tempting than my many-lines helper method. But I urge you to avoid Regex when it isn't absolutely necessary. Regex is an overkill here, and it will hit performance.

Comment: @SimpleVar That's a fair point, but this regular expression isn't having to do much work (i.e. minimal backtracking). It might be an elegant solution that's fast enough in practice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm basically explaining the solution through the comments,
so you can just read out the comments alone and get the idea.

Note I'm using `decimal` as the final result. But you can use `float` or `double` if you wish. The general approach remains valid.

```
string str = "123,456.7";

// Check if its a simple integer (no floating point or thousands separators)
if (str.Length <= 3)
    return (decimal)int.Parse(str);

// Get the floating-point character from the string
char floatingPointChar = str[str.Length - 2];

// Based on the floating-point character,
//   we assure the string is in a standard format of "000,000.0"
switch (floatPointChar)
{
    case '.':
        // If the floating point is a .
        //   the number is already in a standard format
        break;
    case ',':
        // put ~ as a temporary floating-point character
        str = str.Replace(',', '~');

        // turn dots into thousand separators
        str = str.Replace('.', ',');

        // put . as floating-point character
        str = str.Replace('~', '.');
        break;
    default:
        // There is actually no floating point,
        //   so just make sure thousand separators are ,
        str = str.Replace('.', ',');
        break;
}

// Now our string is in a standard format
//   , for thousands separators
//   . for floating point
return decimal.Parse(str, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

---

*Edit: I completely ignored the fact that thousand separators can be omitted altogether. See null's answer for more inspiration*

Answer (score 0):

This is a very nasty way of doing it:

```
  private static string FormatIntString(string input)
    {
        if (input.IndexOf('.') != input.LastIndexOf('.')) 
        {
            if (input.Contains(","))
            {
                //this case-> Ava.bytes -> 147.258.369,5 =>147258369.5
                return DoFormat(input.Replace(".", "").Replace(',', '.'));
            }
            else
            {
                // this case->  Ava.bytes -> 147.258.369 => 147258369.0
                return DoFormat(input.Replace(".", ""));                   
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (input.Contains('.'))
            {
                //this case -> Ava.bytes -> 147,258,369.5 =>147258369.5
                return DoFormat(input.Replace(",", ""));                   
            }
            else
            {
                //this case -> Ava.bytes -> 147,258,369 => 147258369.0
                return DoFormat(input.Replace(",", ""));
            }
        }
    }
    public static string DoFormat(string myNumber)
    {
        var s = string.Format("{0:0.00}", myNumber);
        if (s[s.Length-2] != '.')            
            return (myNumber + ".0");            
        else            
            return s;            
    }
```

Keep in mind that this only works for strings with at least two ',' or '.'.

The simplified code:

```
 private static string FormatIntString(string input)
    {
        if (input.IndexOf('.') != input.LastIndexOf('.'))
            if (input.Contains(","))
                return DoFormat(input.Replace(".", "").Replace(',', '.'));
            else
                return DoFormat(input.Replace(".", ""));
        else            
            if (input.Contains('.'))
                return DoFormat(input.Replace(",", ""));
            else
                return DoFormat(input.Replace(",", ""));            
    }

    public static string DoFormat(string myNumber)
    {
        var s = string.Format("{0:0.00}", myNumber);
        if (s[s.Length - 2] != '.')
            return (myNumber + ".0");
        else
            return s;
    }
```